# Where to use/put jQuery in ASP MVC .Net Core?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I learned that it is recommended to load jQuery at the end of the page (aka footer)

I am currently experimenting with the Scaffold template from the MVC project.
Now, my scenario is that I have a _Layout where jQuery/script/bootstrap are loaded in the footer.
Says I have a view called "Index.cshtml" that will use _Layout.cshtml as layout.
And inside "Index.cshtml", I am just having something as simple as this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').on('click', function (e) {
        alert("hey");
    });       
});
</script>
<button id="test">test</button>
```

My questions is:

I want to bind event to the button using jQuery. How can i call $(document).ready... inside "Index.cshtml" so I can achieve this in the **most efficient way**? (since the jQuery is loaded later on at the footer and I want to write my code in the corresponding page instead of in a shared page like _Layout.cshtml). I was thinking to load jQuery in the view, but that would make it a duplicate load wouldn't it?

**Solution**

In case anyone ran in the the same question like me, please check out Robert's answer below.

Basically the Scaffold template of ASP MVC .Net Core defined a @Section named "Scripts". Therefore, if we define that Script in our View, it will be loaded into the footer of _Layout right after the scripts for jquery/js are loaded.

Comment: You put jQuery in the _Layout. The `$(document).ready(function ()` will just work in the Index.cshtml page as expected. If you need different .js files for different pages, just create multiple _Layout pages with different names.

Comment: @Steve unfortunately I tried that and it didn't work. Seems like at the time it was load, the jQuery script is not loaded just yet. I got the error message "$ is not define" in the console log

Comment: Do you have this line in the <head> tag?  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @benmartin101 I didn't include it. Reason being it will be loaded later in the footer section of the _Layout as mentioned, therefore doing so would cause jQuery to be loaded twice, and I don't want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways, but why not give the script section a try?

```
@section Scripts {
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/main.js"></script>
}
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Or in your case:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#test').on('click', function (e) {
            alert("hey");
        });       
    });
    </script>
 }
```